# How to check typeof of parameter with multiple interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeof

The below code throws error on if(typeof item===game)

Now, my intention is simple. I want to use function hello but I might pass either a 'game' OR 'tame' object in it.

And on basis of what type of object is passed, I want to take action on it.

```
function hello (item : tame|game):any{
    if(typeof item === game)
        console.log(item.BB)
}

interface tame{
        AA:string
}
interface game{
    BB:number
}
```

Code snippet on typescript playground: [HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgBRxgUwLbIFzIwCG2mAPgOYmYCUeREAngN7DLvJwioyMAOmBCE5ZcAXgnIqpGmw7yoSAM4IANpgB0qhBXSiNAIQOyAvsGBwIWAE4giUTIWqt58gIJu8SmNcsVgZpY2dg5SznLsRngQYNgARpjWAebAQA)

Comment: Shouldn't this be `typeof item === 'game'`?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"game"' have no overlap.(2367)

Comment: Note that it is conventional to give non-primitive types names in UpperCamelCase; please consider changing your `tame` and `game` type names  to `Tame` and `Game`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only check primitive types like string, boolean, number e.c. by

```
if (typeof t === <type>)
```

When you have a interface you need to check how you can say what Type it has like:

```
function isGame(o: tame | game): o is game {
  return typeof (o as game).BB === number; 
}
```

There should be a difference between this two interfaces. One should have one property the other one doesn't have. You can also just check if it has this specific property.

```
function isGame(o: tame | game): o is game {
  if ((o as Game).BB === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Btw, I would suggest you to capitalize interface names like

```
interface Tame {
  AA:string
}
```

Comment: the above code says the following 
`Property 'BB' does not exist on type 'tame'.`

Comment: Sry forgot a questionmark ("?") before o. I've edited the answer.

Comment: `Property 'BB' does not exist on type 'tame'`
still the same error

Comment: Yes, sry it's fixed now. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=21&pln=2&pc=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgcQIYFsCmAKOALkQBVsdEAfRTXASmLmRRvMQG8AoRZYRPAogwtaOOgDoAQpMQBeeYnAATHMBhgcSuh249EAJxxQQ+pMAwAbFDgDcugL67Dx04ij6Qtzo87qoOfXMICjJcHT1EAEFIwhR3dQBzb18wf0CMYNYwrgjpQjAQLAAjAOTOCAQ4t2JQilkOKJjEACIACxwLCzhmxHs7CrAUOAsccS6EvFRRPCg6OhsgA